# How to remove double quotes and ';' from header in PySpark

Tags: python, csv, file, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to remove "" and ; from my CSV file in PySpark. The data in CSV looks like below:

```
age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y"
58;"management";"married";"tertiary";"no";2143;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";261;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
```

Code I am using is:

```py
df = spark.read.options(delimiter=';').csv("C:/Project_bankdata.csv", header=True)
df1 = df.select([F.regexp_replace(c, '"', '').alias(c) for c in df.columns])
df1.show(10,truncate=0)
```

Output:

```
|"age;""job""   |""marital""|""education""|""default""|""balance""|""housing""|""loan""|""contact""|""day""|""month""|""duration""|""campaign""|""pdays""|""previous""|""poutcome""|""y"""|
+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------+-------+---------+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+------+
|58;management  |married    |tertiary     |no         |2143       |yes        |no      |unknown    |5      |may      |261         |1           |-1       |0           |unknown     |no    |
```

I am able to get rid of quotes from data, but not from the header. How can I remove double quotes from header as well?

Comment: Using the input that you provided, everything works well. You should check your real input once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only able to reproduce your output if I used this input CSV:

```
"age;""job"";""marital"";""education"";""default"";""balance"";""housing"";""loan"";""contact"";""day"";""month"";""duration"";""campaign"";""pdays"";""previous"";""poutcome"";""y"""
"58;"management"";"married";"tertiary";"no";2143;"yes";"no";"unknown";5;"may";261;1;-1;0;"unknown";"no"
```

You can read the CSV as text file, remove all the double quotes `"` from every line and then make a dataframe.

```py
rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(r"C:\temp\temp.csv")
rdd = rdd.map(lambda line: line.replace('"', '').split(';'))

header = rdd.first()
df = rdd.filter(lambda line: line != header).toDF(header)

df.show()
# +---+----------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+-------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
# |age|       job|marital|education|default|balance|housing|loan|contact|day|month|duration|campaign|pdays|previous|poutcome|  y|
# +---+----------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+-------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
# | 58|management|married| tertiary|     no|   2143|    yes|  no|unknown|  5|  may|     261|       1|   -1|       0| unknown| no|
# +---+----------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----+-------+---+-----+--------+--------+-----+--------+--------+---+
```

**Note.** This effectively removes string notation from the CSV file. So, this will only work well, if you don't have such values which contain `;` inside them.

Comment: Above solution works for me but is there any way to solve this with SparkSession and not with sparkContext?

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()

Comment: There is no problem but I heard that sparkContext is replaced by SparkSession which is why I am try with later.

Comment: [This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/sparksession-vs-sparkcontext-vs-sqlcontext-vs-hivecontext-741d50c9486a) tells that "Spark 2.0 introduced a new entry point called **SparkSession** that essentially **replaced both SQLContext and HiveContext**. Additionally, it gives to developers immediate access to SparkContext." So... **SparkContext** is not a deprecated feature.